# hours, minutes seconds separation showing as underscore instead of colon

Tags: javascript, vue.js, date, time, momentjs

I am using moment.js to get the current date and time and I am trying to format it in the following format

```
'MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'
```

But the issue here is that the separation between hours, minutes and seconds is showing as underscore instead of colons. This is the how I am implementing it.

```
download() {
  var url = OFFERS_URL + '?';
  this.$axios.get(url, responseType: 'blob' })
  .then(response => {
    var file = new Blob([response.data]);
    FileSaver.saveAs(file, 'Offers ' + moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a') + '.xls');
  });
}
```

The downloaded file name showes as

```
Offers April 20th 2021, 1_26_59 PM
```

but it should be

```
Offers April 20th 2021, 1:26:59 PM
```

Comment: What OS are you using? Stab in the dark but if you're on windows or mac colons aren't allowed in filenames so it's possible FileSaver is stripping those with valid characters.

Comment: @Phix can you suggest the best way for displaying time in any other format?

Comment: @user12763413 What's wrong with including the underscores?

Comment: Yea, don't use invalid characters. It's not a big deal to have underscores instead of colons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this format for the date part of your filename:

```
moment().format('DD-YYYY-MM_hh-mm-ss-a')
```

According to IBM on OS file naming conventions (see reference https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.1?topic=files-file-naming-conventions)

The name of each file must be unique within the directory where it is stored. This ensures that the file also has a unique path name in the file system.

File naming guidelines are:

- A file name can be up to 255 characters long and can contain letters,
  numbers, and underscores.
- The operating system is case-sensitive, which means it distinguishes
  between uppercase and lowercase letters in file names. Therefore,
  FILEA, FiLea, and filea are three distinct file names, even if they
  reside in the same directory.
- File names should be as descriptive and    meaningful as possible.
- Directories follow the same naming conventions as files.
- Certain characters have special meaning to the operating system.
  Avoid using these characters when you are naming files.

These characters include the following:

`/ \ " ' * ; - ? [ ] ( ) ~ ! $ { } &lt > # @ & | space tab newline`

Comment: I agree your suggested filename is a good choice, but what you are quoting about file naming conventions is from IBM AIX and doesn't mention _which_ filesystem (e.g. ext3, zfs, ext4) which is generally _more important_ than which OS is running. The OP doesn't mention an OS or filesystem, but if colon isn't allowed it's likely a Mac or Windows setup; *nix systems mostly _do_ allow colon in filenames.

Comment: Generally you should not use some special characters in filename as listed above including **:**. If you ever did kind of mass file renaming on most unix systems, you should be aware of it. Some special characters have to be escape, which do not make the file renaming process easy. Also portability of files between systems could become a big issue also.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formate for the file name according to your need

```
const today_date = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h_mm_ss A');
console.log("Offers "+ today_date +".xls");
```